# Change status bar color dynamically in Swift 4

Tags: ios, swift

I would like to change the status bar color between `.lightContent` and `.default` dynamically (since my background can change in the same ViewController).

I have tried to make a function for this that looks like this:

```
func changeStatusBar(useDefault: Bool) {
    if useDefault {
        var preferredStatusBarStyle: UIStatusBarStyle {
            return .default
        }
    } else {
        var preferredStatusBarStyle: UIStatusBarStyle {
            return .lightContent
        }
    }
    setNeedsStatusBarAppearanceUpdate()
}
```

But no luck. Every guide i found online (or here on Stackoverflow) only shows how to change the statusBar once, and not on and off through a function.

I have also set `View controller-based status bar appearance` to `NO` in the `info.plist` file.

The line i used to use is `UIApplication.shared.statusBarStyle = .lightContent` - but since this is deprecated since iOS9, i can't use it anymore.

Anyone has some idea how I can change this dynamically?

Answer (score 40, accepted):

Create a property with type `UIStatusBarStyle` and return the value in  `preferredStatusBarStyle`

And you can change its value whenever you need and call `setNeedsStatusBarAppearanceUpdate()`

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {

    override var preferredStatusBarStyle: UIStatusBarStyle {
        return self.style
    }
    var style:UIStatusBarStyle = .default

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
    }

    @IBAction func changeStyle(_ sender: UIButton) {
        if self.style == .lightContent {
            self.style = .default
        } else {
            self.style = .lightContent
        }
        setNeedsStatusBarAppearanceUpdate()
    }
}
```

> ```
> override var preferredStatusBarStyle: UIStatusBarStyle { return self.style }
> ```
>
> wont be called if you have embedded your view controller in a
>   navigation controller You should change bar style of your navigation controller
>
> ```
> self.navigationController?.navigationBar.barStyle = //newStyle
> ```

[image]

Comment: I tried this in a new project and it works flawlessly! But in my existing app the `override var preferredStatusBarStyle: UIStatusBarStyle {
        return self.style
    }` isn't being called upon change... any ideas on why this could be? Both `var style : UIStatusBarStyle = .default` and `setNeedsStatusBarAppearanceUpdate()` is being called...

Comment: Thank you so much, this is a great solution!

Comment: @bsod var style isn't a global variable. It is an instance property of the ViewController class

Comment: This worked perfectly for me......use .black for white color and .default for black color of status bar

Answer (score 5):

I hope below code will use for your need (for Swift4):

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    let statusBar = UIApplication.shared.value(forKey: "statusBar") as? UIView
    if statusBar?.responds(to: #selector(setter: UIView.backgroundColor)) ?? false {
        statusBar?.backgroundColor = .green
    }
}
```

Alternatively, you could try this:

```
   if let StatusbarView = UIApplication.shared.value(forKey: "statusBar") as? UIView {
                StatusbarView.backgroundColor = .green
   }
```

Answer (score 1):

Override `preferredStatusBarStyle` and call `setNeedsStatusBarAppearanceUpdate()` when it needs an update. In my example I used a simple dark mode controlled by a boolean property `useDarkMode`. As soon as it gets changed the UI is updated (including the status bar):

```
var useDarkMode = false {
    didSet {
        if useDarkMode != oldValue {
            updateUI()
        }
    }
}

private func updateUI() {
    UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.25) {
        if self.useDarkMode {
            self.view.backgroundColor = .darkGray
            self.view.tintColor = .white
        } else {
            self.view.backgroundColor = .white
            self.view.tintColor = nil
        }

        self.setNeedsStatusBarAppearanceUpdate()
    }
}

override var preferredStatusBarStyle: UIStatusBarStyle {
    return useDarkMode ? .lightContent : .default
}
```